# Xamarin -- Radiobutton visual state doesn't update after setting the value in a viewmodel when using Syncfusion's SfPopupLayout

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, mvvm, viewmodel

When working with data-binding I've run into an issue where the radiobutton won't update visually, but the value is correct. I have a RadiobuttonGroup.GroupName & a RadioButtonGroup.SelectedValue. The SelectedValue is data-bound to my ViewModel with a {Binding Selection}. Selection is also declared in my ViewModel.

Whenever I change the RadioButton's selection to a button that isn't selected, OnPropertyChanged(); goes off thrice. (I suppose that is due to the fact that there's three buttons in the view, could be wrong here.) Resulting in the value being selected and being handed over to my data-bound Selection. But the visual state of the button doesn't change. The radiobuttons are located in a SfPopupLayout pop-up. It always works as expected the first time the pop-up is initialized and served in the view. But with every subsequent serving, it bugs out visually. Resulting in having to click the radiobutton multiple times to make the visual-state change.

There really isn't much going on, just that Selection is stored in my ViewModel. I've checked the Xamarin-Examples-Demos on GitHub with regards to RadioButtons & data-binding and I'm not able to reproduce the same issues I'm experiencing with the demo.

XAML code snippet;

```
<StackLayout HeightRequest="160"
             Grid.Row="2"
             RadioButtonGroup.GroupName="WeekSelection"
             RadioButtonGroup.SelectedValue="{Binding Selection}">
                <RadioButton Padding="5"
                             BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource BlockBackgroundColor}"       
                             Content="{markup:Translate Week_Selection}"
                             Value="{markup:Translate Week_Selection}"/>
                <BoxView Style="{StaticResource SeperatorLineStyle}"/>
                <RadioButton Padding="5"
                             BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource BlockBackgroundColor}"
                             Content="{markup:Translate TwoWeek_Selection}"
                             Value="{markup:Translate TwoWeek_Selection}"/>
                <BoxView Style="{StaticResource SeperatorLineStyle}"/>
                <RadioButton Padding="5"
                             BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource BlockBackgroundColor}"
                             Content="{markup:Translate Month_Selection}"
                             Value="{markup:Translate Month_Selection}"/>
                <BoxView Style="{StaticResource SeperatorLineStyle}"/>
</StackLayout>
```

UPDATE: Seems like it has something to do with switching views. Whenever I go to my settings-page to change the selection of the radiobuttons, OnPropertyChanged(); is only fired once. But whenever I close the view and return to it, it fires it off twice. And subsequently with every switch it increases the amount of times OnPropertyChanged(); is called. Value still works properly, just the visual state isn't updated.

UPDATE 2: I'm pretty sure it has to do with the pop-up that's generated containing the radiobuttons. Here's the code that initializes the pop-up with the radiobuttons in them;

```
        public void ShowAmountOfWeeksPopup()
        {
            _selectWeeksToViewPopupControl = new SelectWeeksToViewPopupControl(this);
            
            _selectWeeksToViewPopupControl.Show();
        }

        public void DismissAmountOfWeeksPopup()
        { 
            _selectWeeksToViewPopupControl.Dismiss();
        }
```

FINAL UPDATE:

According to SyncFusion this is a bug, ended up creating a forum post on their support forums and they ended up supplying me with a fix. If anybody ever runs into the same issue, please refer to the following link; https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/171545/radiobuttons-not-working-properly-when-closing-and-re-opening-a-popup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Xamarin -- Radiobutton visual state doesn't update after setting the
> value in a viewmodel.

I couldn't see other code of your app. So I did a test based on the sample code [GroupedRadioButtonsViewModelPage.xaml](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/main/UserInterface/RadioButtonDemos/RadioButtonDemos/GroupedRadioButtonsViewModelPage.xaml), but I couldn't reproduce this problem.

You can refer to the following code:

The `GroupedRadioButtonsViewModelPage.xaml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="RadioButtonDemos.GroupedRadioButtonsViewModelPage"
             Title="Grouped RadioButtons ViewModel demo">
    <StackLayout Margin="10"
                 RadioButtonGroup.GroupName="{Binding GroupName}"
                 RadioButtonGroup.SelectedValue="{Binding Selection}">
        <Label Text="What's your favorite animal?" />
        <RadioButton Content="Cat"
                     Value="Cat" />
        <RadioButton Content="Dog"
                     Value="Dog" />
        <RadioButton Content="Elephant"
                     Value="Elephant" />
        <RadioButton Content="Monkey"
                     Value="Monkey"/>
        <Label x:Name="animalLabel">
            <Label.FormattedText>
                <FormattedString>
                    <Span Text="You have chosen:" />
                    <Span Text="{Binding Selection}" />
                </FormattedString>
            </Label.FormattedText>
        </Label>


        <Button  Text="test"  Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

The `GroupedRadioButtonsViewModelPage.xaml.cs`

```
public partial class GroupedRadioButtonsViewModelPage : ContentPage
{

    AnimalViewModel model;
    public GroupedRadioButtonsViewModelPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        model = new AnimalViewModel();
        BindingContext = model;

        //BindingContext = new AnimalViewModel
        //{
        //    GroupName = "animals",
        //    Selection = "Monkey"
        //};
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        model.Selection = "Dog";
    }
}
```

The `AnimalViewModel.cs`

```
public class AnimalViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string groupName;
    object selection;


    public AnimalViewModel() {

        GroupName = "animals";
        Selection = "Elephant";
    }

    public string GroupName
    {
        get => groupName;
        set
        {
            groupName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(GroupName));
        }
    }

    public object Selection
    {
        get => selection;
        set
        {
            selection = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Selection));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**Note:**

I added a button, and when clicking the Button, we can change the value of `Selection` of the ViewModel(`AnimalViewModel`), then the UI will automatically refresh.

Comment: Hi Jessie, thanks for replying! It seems it has to do with the fact that with every time I'm creating a new Page, that there's something going on with the GC not disposing the older page. Resulting in OnPropertyChanged() firing off multiple times. Seems to me that there's something wrong with my code. Thanks for the reply, though!

Comment: Have you resolved your problem?

Comment: Sadly, no. It seems like it has to do with the plug-in we're using. SyncFusion's SfPopupLayout seems to not dispose of the pop-up properly when creating a new pop-up every time a button is pressed to show the settings pop-up, resulting in visual bugs. So this is probably a really niche issue. I've added an update to the question and updated the question to be more specific.

Comment: If it is convinient for you,could you please post a basic demo to github or onedriver so that we can test on our side?

Comment: Took me a little while to get the plug-in to work properly, but here goes. I was able to reproduce the exact same issue. Simply click the show pop up button, select one of three radiobuttons. Close the pop up and re-open it again. Set a breakpoint on OnPropertyChanged(); and you'll notice that it'll fire off multiple times. Visual state doesn't change either. https://github.com/TwisterTies/sfpopupradiobuttons

Comment: Every time you pop a dialog box, you're creating a new page object with all the original values. So, I'm not sure why you're adding the `Save` button to the page, and it just dismiss the dialog. And I don't see where you're changing Selection.

Comment: I honestly don't really know what I'm doing wrong at this point. I feel like it has to do with the plugin. I just rewrote the code, moved the page creation to the constructor, resulting in a single instance. I also temporarily removed the viewmodel, leaving every button unchecked. I open the popup, I click one of the radiobuttons, close it, reopen it (I'm aware there's no data, since I didn't explicitly saved it) and I just click any random button that's unchecked. I still have to click twice. Could it be that it's a bug with the popup plug-in we're using?

Comment: `I still have to click twice.`  How can we reproduce this problem? Could you please post the steps to reproduce this problem?

Comment: Updated the repo, sorry about that.

Comment: Yes,it is the case as you said. But the same code(RadioButton) in the `ContentPage` does not cause this problem.

Comment: Hi Jessie, then according to your diagnosis I suppose it has to do with the pop-up plugin we're using. I'll contact Syncfusion to let them know we're facing this issue. Thanks for your replies and have a good New Year's Eve! :)